# before и after расширяют родительский блок

Tags: html, css

Есть логотип, размером 256х256. И есть 2псевдоэлемента before и after, которые увеличивают логотип и при ховрее уменьшают его.

Но эти псевдоэлементы увеличивают ширину и высоту родителя на процент увеличения который им установлен.
Как избежать этого, и сделать что бы ховер работа **ТОЛЬКО** при наведении на родителя блок?

```css
a.logo{
 display: block;
 width: 256px;
 height: 256px;
  max-width: 256px;
 max-height: 256px;
 background: url(http://i665.photobucket.com/albums/vv20/Davidmj444/Lion_256x256.png) no-repeat center top;
 outline: 1px solid lime;
 position: relative;
}

a.logo::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
 width: 256px;
 height: 256px;
 background: url(http://i665.photobucket.com/albums/vv20/Davidmj444/Lion_256x256.png) no-repeat center top;
 transform: scale(1.3) rotate(30deg);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -ie-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a.logo:hover::after {
 transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="logo"></a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mznu4979/

Answer (score 1):

Поигрался, и вот ответ:

В обычном состоянии для ::before, ::after нужно дать:

```
visibility:hidden;
```

А при наведении

```
visibility: visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

В обычном состоянии для `::before` и `::after` нужно дать:

```
opacity: 0;
```

А при наведении:

```
opacity: 1;
```

Comment: Если блоку сделать прозрачность 0 - то при наведении на место где  стоит блок - все равно отработает ховер. А от этого и нужно было избавится.

Comment: @user190134 так visibility:hidden; также само работает.

Comment: visibility - это видимость элемента на странице, а opacity - это прозрачность, это разные свойства

Comment: @user190134 в данной ситуации их действие идентично.